# 2018 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2018 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://engineering.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 7):

This seems like as good a place as any to state publicly that I will not be nominating in this election. Since this site launched I've taken on more responsibility at work, my family has grown, and I don't feel I've been able to put in the time here that the community deserves from members with this level of access/privilege. I'm looking forward to others in the community stepping up into that role and I wish the best to all nominees.

Comment: Thanks for your three years of service as moderator!

Comment: Thank you, Air! That being said, the initial announcement said current moderators wouldn't have to renominate themselves for this election. If you wish to step down from  the ♦, you might have to request it, since I think you'll otherwise remain one even after the election.

Comment: Thanks for your work throughout the years!

Comment: Thanks Air!  I didn't know this but I remembered when you were more active.